# Installing Drivers from ATI Website?

Tags: drivers, ati, gpu

When I click `About This Computer` -> `Graphics`, it shows none.

Also the fan of my Laptop is always on even though CPU usage is below 5%, hence it is wasting tremendous amount of electricity because the AC Adaptor becomes very hot.

So I think the Drivers for ATI Radeon HD 7670m Graphics are not installed properly.
So I downloaded the drivers for Linux_64 from ATI website.

It was a .zip file. After extracting it gave a .run file. When I double clicked the file a window opened containing some text about the driver. From `System Monitor` I found that a process `gedit` was running at 100%. It was showing a progress bar which incremented extremely slowly. So I canceled it.

So I would like to know how do I install the drivers from the .run file?

Comment: Maybe one should explain what installing drivers from Ubuntu Repos means: Ubuntu by default uses open source drivers (which are less buggy, but also draw more power), yet it also supplies you with a convenient way to get the "official" drivers from AMD without going to their website and installing them by hand: Go to System Settings -> Additional Drivers, select fglrx-updates and click the activate button. Done. For your information, the .run file you got from AMD has to get the executable permission in order for you to run it (chmod +x <filename>), but anyhow, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: ok @soulsource got it!
I will try that. Thanks :)